# Nested MySQL Statement Issue

Tags: sql, mysql, case

I've got the following Generated Column modification that is throwing an error for me. I modified it recently with a similar nested case but realized after the fact I didn't save the query and I need to update one check so it needs to be updated.

```
 ALTER TABLE
    `t1` MODIFY COLUMN `criteria` GENERATED ALWAYS AS(
        CASE WHEN `status` = 'Active' THEN
            CASE WHEN `exempt` = 'FALSE' AND `age` < 35 THEN
                CASE WHEN `experience` = "Pro" AND `rule` = 'Descendent' THEN 6 
                WHEN `experience` = "Pro" AND `rule` != 'Descendent' THEN 5 
                WHEN `experience` = 'Division I' AND `rule` = 'Descendent' THEN 5 
                WHEN `experience` = 'Division I' AND `rule` != 'Descendent' THEN 4 
                WHEN `experience` = 'Division II' AND `rule` = 'Descendent' THEN 4 
                WHEN `experience` = 'Division II' AND `rule` != 'Descendent' THEN 3 
                WHEN `experience` = 'Division III' AND `rule` = 'Descendent' THEN 3 
                WHEN `experience` = 'Division III' AND `rule` != 'Descendent' THEN 2 
                WHEN `experience` = 'NAIA' AND `rule` = 'Descendent' THEN 3 
                WHEN `experience` = 'NAIA' AND `rule` != 'Descendent' THEN 2 
                WHEN `experience` = 'Junior College' AND `rule` = 'Descendent' THEN 2 
                WHEN `experience` = 'Junior College' AND `rule` != 'Descendent' THEN 1 
                WHEN `experience` = 'High School' AND `rule` = 'Descendent' THEN 1 
                ELSE 0
                END
         ELSE 0
         END
 ELSE 0
 END
) STORED
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here? I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm missing. Thanks in advance!
Here is the error from MySql:

```
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GENERATED ALWAYS AS(
        CASE WHEN `status` = 'Active' THEN
            CA' at line 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even for generated columns, you must specify a data type as part of the column definition.

```
ALTER TABLE
`t1` MODIFY COLUMN `criteria` _______________________ GENERATED ALWAYS AS ...
                              ^ data type goes here ^
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, that was exactly what I was missing!